# How to check and load activity as per the result

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a check on onCreate if the database is empty I want to load userdetails.java and if database contain data then MainActivity.java. Any example of code snippet will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One `Activity` must be your initial "main" activity that automatically is loaded first, I don't think what you want can be done unless you use a sort of splash activity first and then choose to load those other ones. Or you could load one of those, do your check and choose to switch or leave it on that activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this right, you will need to think out the overall flow of your application.

From your description, here's the one that seems most probable.

- Start Main as usual, unconditionally
- If Main determines that UserDetails be started, use startActivity to open it and
  immediately call finish() on Main! That's important: it will prevent
  the Back button from screwing up your screen flow
- When done with UserDetails, have it call startActivity to invoke Main and then
  finish() itself

Answer (score 1):

You can start MainActivity and check in `onResume` if there's no data. If so, then start UserDetails. When the user is done entering data just call `finish()` (from UserDetails). When MainActivity is resumed it will look for the user data, find it, and work as normal.